# A bit wrong average color. (np.mean())

Tags: python, image, numpy, rgb

I wrote a script, that writes average color of image in a file. But, it returns a *bit* wrong values.

```py
# coding=utf-8

from __future__ import print_function
import cv2, sys, os
import numpy as np

palette = []

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print(u'Drag file on me.')
    print(u'(Press Enter to close)',end='')
    raw_input()
    sys.exit()

if not os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
    print(u'Invalid file name.')
    print(u'(Press Enter to close)',end='')
    raw_input()
    sys.exit()
for file in sys.argv[1:]:
    im = cv2.imread(file)
    if im is None:
        print(u'The specified file is corrupted or is not a picture.')
        print(u'(Press Enter to close)',end='')
        raw_input()
        sys.exit()

    colors = np.unique(im.reshape(-1, im.shape[2]), axis=0)
    color = np.flip(colors.mean(axis=0,dtype=np.float64).astype(int)).tolist()
    palette.append([color,os.path.basename(file)[:-4]])
palette = np.array(palette)
palette = palette[palette[:,0].argsort(kind='mergesort')]
out = open('palette.txt','w')
out.write(str(palette.tolist()))
out.close()
```

Example: [(image)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fEAjiXUty4ES5QPq4dAG2iDYO0ZWrzHv) - in Photoshop, and [here](https://matkl.github.io/average-color/), average color is [105, 99, 89], but my script returns [107,100,90]

Comment: Why do you use `np.unique`? Do you want it to be the mean of the pallet or of the colors actually used the image with their frequency?

Comment: Thank you very much! I removed `np.unique()`, and that works as intended!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to remove the `unique` command to reproduce what the javascript is doing. Replace it with

```
colors = im.reshape(-1, im.shape[2])
```

The difference is that you average the palate (every color used appears once), while the script averages the image (averages colors as they appear in the image).

Answer (score 0):

Change the line with

`colors = np.unique(im.reshape(-1, im.shape[2]), axis=0)`

to

`colors = im.reshape(-1, im.shape[2])`

For an average color calculation, it matters if a color is used more than once, so using `np.unique` will give an incorrect result.

Comment: Thank you too, stephen!